# ¿Cómo cambiar el estilo de de un template solamente mientras se está ejecutando una función?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Lo que quiero hacer es que **solamente mientras se ejecuta la función del** `controller`, que se cambie el estilo del `temlate`. Por ejemplo: el `template: '<a class="reload" ng-click="refresh()"></a>'` tiene una **clase** llamada **"reload"** y quiero que **mientras se ejecute la función** tenga la clase **"reloading"** **-pero solamente mientras se ejecuta la función**.

La función lo que hace es recargar la ruta donde estés, si hay una mejor forma de implementarlo pues también sería bueno que me dieran un ejemplo.

```js
app.component('reloadComponent', {
    template: '<a id="reload" ng-click="refresh()"></a>',
    controller: ['$scope','$route', function reloadComponentCtrl($scope,$route){
      $scope.refresh = function(){
        $route.reload();
      };
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes definir un valor `$scope` con un valor por defecto, cuando haga `ng-click` y entra a la función cambie ese valor por defecto. Y con el tag `ng-class` le dices que tenga una clase pero que cambie de clase siempre y cuando tu valor por defecto cambie.

```
app.component('reloadComponent', {
    template: template: '<a id="reload" ng-class="{tu_clase: cambiar_clase == true}" ng-click="refresh()"></a>'
    controller: ['$scope','$route', function reloadComponentCtrl($scope,$route){
      $scope.cambiar_clase = false;
      $scope.refresh = function(){
        $route.reload();
        $scope.cambiar_clase = true;
      };
      $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function($currentRoute, $previousRoute) {
          $scope.cambiar_clase = false;
      });
    }]
});
```

Comment: Al ejecutar la función se queda con la clase y no vuelve a la normalidad, se queda con ella?

Comment: @adrianojosue puedes explicarte mejor? una vez que termine de ejecutar la funcion, podrias dejar `$scope.cambiar_clase = false`

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es que solamente se le agregue esa clase si la función se está ejecutando. pero en tu ejemplo al ejecutar la función se mantienen con la clase.

Comment: @adrianojosue edite mi respuesta, hay un evento $routeChangeSuccess que una vez que termine de ejecutarse el reload puedes volver a inicializar tu valor